# Securing a .NET framework

Tags: .net, security

The NSA provides a guide to securing version 2.0 of the .NET framework here: http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/app/I731-008R-2006.pdf

I was wondering if they provide guides for later versions e.g. version 3.0 or 3.5?

Also, I'm interested in any other links especially those from NIST or NSA on .NET security.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the document, none of this has changed until .Net 4.0.

Remember that the only differences between .Net 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 is new DLLs and a new compiler.

(Unless you're using WCF or AJAX)